# JSONObject.keySet() - removing single key obtained from JSONObject.keySet() also removes same key entry in JSONObject?

Tags: java, json, set, key, org.json

Why does removing key obtained from json.keySet() method, removes entry of the particular key from the corresponding json object also ? My guess is that it may be due to reference operations. Correct me if I'm wrong ?

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("country", "england");
obj.put("city", "london");
System.out.println(obj);   //1
Set<String> keys = obj.keySet();
System.out.println(keys);  //2
keys.remove("country");
System.out.println(keys);  //3
System.out.println(obj);   //4
```

The output :

```
{"country":"england","city":"london"} //1
[country, city]  //2
[city]           //3
{"city":"london"}//4
```

Comment: Please read the Javadoc for the `Map#keySet()` method to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

For the `JSONObject` implementations I could find, the `JSONObject.keySet()` method either

- inherits from `java.util.Map.keySet()` (e.g., [`javax.json.JsonObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html)); or
- delegates to `java.util.Map.keySet()` (e.g. [`org.json.JSONObject`](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java), which you seem to be using).

However it may be, the JavaDoc for [`java.util.Map.keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) states (emphasis mine):

> Returns a `Set` view of the keys contained in this map. [...]
>   **The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map**, [...]